# Get EditText Background Resource

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

How can I get my EditText Background Resource in my Android Activity?

My short Example App is this:

```
Button1: EditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redstyle); //Red style xml
Button2: EditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.greenstyle); // Green style xml

if(????????????????????????????????????){
    Toast.makeText(this,"Green is selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else{
    Toast.makeText(this,"Red is selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: You should probably introduce a state variable which will help you control this. EditText is in presentation layer which reacts to state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do it to create an HashMap, and when you insert a background in a EditText just map it

```
HashMap<EditText,Integer> hashMap;
edit_text.setBackgroundResources(R.drawable.redstyle);
hashMap.put(edit_text,R.drawable.redstyle);

if(hashMap.get(edit_text)==R.drawable.redstyle)
{
    //do something
}else{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: my  error is: Cannot resolve method "getBackgroundDrawable()" :'(

Comment: can you help me how can i map my background color with a button?

Comment: You need to explain better what you want

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
if(edit_text.getBackground()==getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redstyle)){
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"red selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }else{
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Green selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: This code show me Green When The Red is selected :'(

Comment: doesn't work for me either.  Annoying since this seems to be the only generic answer on all of SO.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was a `editTextState`. Something like this

```
Button1: EditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redstyle); //Red style xml
         editTextState = 1;

Button2: EditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.greenstyle); // Green style xml
          editTextState = 2;

if(editTextState == 2){
    Toast.makeText(this,"Green is selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else{
    Toast.makeText(this,"Red is selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

You can define the state value according the editText background color you have set on the xml layout. For example if you set the editText with red background:

```
int editTextState = 1;
```